# JMenu popup only sometimes works

Tags: java, swing

I am having issue with `JMenu` popup. It only sometimes works. Sometimes I don't get a java popup at all. Sometimes my File and Edit options are completely missing. This is what my code looks like.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class menu {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu file = new JMenu ("File");
        mb.add(file);
        JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
        mb.add(edit);

        f.setJMenuBar(mb);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Call `setVisible` on the `JFrame` only after you have initialised the core UI...

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
// Don't call this here...
//f.setVisible(true);
f.setSize(400,400);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();

JMenu file = new JMenu ("File");
mb.add(file);
JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
mb.add(edit);

f.setJMenuBar(mb);
// Call it here
f.setVisible(true);
```

Also, make sure you are creating/updating the UI only from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: am I correctly using Event Dispatching Thread or is my code to short to tell? Will I also need to use this to test it? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#isEventDispatchThread--

Comment: No you're not (initialising the UI within the context of the EDT) and yes, you'll need to use `SwingUtilites.inokeLater` or `EventQueue.invokeLater`, they both do the same thing...